# SQL/Sybase query group by a substring of a column value

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

I am making a simple select query with the following result -

```
select source_uri from image
```

--

```
source_uri

"image/30022/A.jpg"
"image/30022/B.jpg"
"image/30022/C.jpg"
"image/30022/D.jpg"
"image/30023/A.jpg"
"image/30023/B.jpg"
"image/30023/C.jpg"
"image/30023/D.jpg"
"image/30024/A.jpg"
"image/30024/B.jpg"
"image/30024/C.jpg"
"image/30024/D.jpg"
```

I want result like -

```
source_uri

"image/30022/A.jpg"
"image/30023/B.jpg"
"image/30024/C.jpg"
```

I tried having a group by clause... but it doesnot group by since the values are different.

--

I am able to use the SUBSTRING_INDEX function in mySQL.

Looking for the exact alternative in Sybase.

Comment: Is there a logic to the result set?

Comment: The logic is to get distinct folder names - "image/30022", "image/30023" ...

Comment: So "image/30022/D.jpg", "image/30023/A.jpg", "image/30024/B.jpg" is an equally valid result?

Comment: That is true! Not interested in filenames right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR MySQL -**

*M Khalid Junaid's answer works great.*

**FOR Sybase -**

I did a lean trick.. not sure how efficient this is -

```
select source_uri from image
```

Problem: To extract "image/30022" from "image/30022/a.jpg"

Solution:

1) Got the file length - `file_length = CHARINDEX('/', reverse(source_uri))`

2) Substring - `SUBSTRING(source_uri, 1, LEN(source_uri) - file_length)`

```
select SUBSTRING(source_uri, 1, LEN(source_uri) - file_length) from image 
group by SUBSTRING(source_uri, 1, LEN(source_uri) - file_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is always the last 6 i.e **D.jpg"**  characters you need to apply group by then you can use the `RIGHT(col,len)`,Right returns the rightmost len characters from the string str, or NULL if any argument is NULL

```
select source_uri 
from image 
GROUP BY RIGHT(source_uri ,6)
```

[**RIGHT(str,len)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right)

Other way you need get the part after last / so use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
select source_uri 
from image 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_uri ,'/',-1)
```

[**SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

EDIT after reading comments

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_uri ,'/',-1) /* will give you  A.jpg*/
```

Now to get remaining part you can do so

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_uri ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_uri ,'/',-1) ,1) /* will give you image/30022/ */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but no... the file name can be of varying length.

Comment: Thank you! This printed the filenames  - A.jpg, B.jpg and so on so forth.... not sure how to break ice to print the file path except the filenames for eg. "image/3022/"

Comment: Also, I need the same alternative in Sybase DB... updating the question. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: @webExplorer Nor familiar with sybase syntax but from [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1260/html/iqref/Substr.htm) you can get it from docs